# Using Windows Hooks to intercept mouse click on my application c++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

In my C++ MFC application I have an ActiveX control on a form. At some point I create and show a new dialog. I don't want the user to be able to click the ActiveX control while this second dialog is up so I tried creating it as a child dialog. However the ActiveX control always appears above the child dialog in Z order. I have tried sending message on the create to change the Z order but nothing worked.

I've tried using Windows Hooks to intercept the mouse click using the following code:

```
GetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)CDWFDLG::ClickProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0)

 LRESULT CALLBACK CDWFDLG::ClickProc(int ncode, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{

if(wparam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
{
    Beep(110, 30);
    return TRUE;
}
return CallNextHookEx(0, ncode, wparam, lparam);
}
```

This blocks all left mouse clicks which is what I want. However it does this on everything, not just on my application. I've tried setting the thread Id using

```
GetCurrentThreadId()
```

and

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(this->m_hWnd, &threadId )
```

However neither of these worked. What should I use to just get the hook to run on my application? Once this is working I was planning on using the coordinates of the click to check whether is was on the new dialog and handle it from there.

Thanks

Comment: Simply showing the dialog modally through `ShowDialog` does not work?

Comment: @Thomas: fully agree. A modal dialog should solve the issue.

Comment: I don't appear to have `ShowDialog` as a method for the dialog. It is definitely using CDialog as a base class. There's `ShowWindow' and `DoModal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't fix the problem using Window Hooks, I think I've fixed it using the dialog properties. I've set the parent dialog's `Control Parent` to True and left everything else in the child dialog's properties to default (`Control` is false and and `Style` is Popup etc).

Now when I call the dialog through `DoModal()` it has focus and doesn't allow clicks on the ActiveX control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)CDWFDLG::ClickProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0)

Means you are hooking globally, all mouse clicks performed.

What you want is to hook WH_MOUSE, with the option GetCurrentThreadId() instead of 0, this will yield the results you want.